# Equation for determining if a range contains one or more #N/A values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm developing a financial model and as a completeness check, I need to provide the user with a completeness check that essentially ensures that a range of data does not have any #N/A errors.  For example, I'd like the equation in J1 to return "Incomplete" if a single cell in the range A1:A80 has an #N/A value and "Complete" if not a single cell has an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A80,"#N/A")
```

So

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A80,"#N/A")>0,"incomplete","Complete")
```

Though sounds like you want something more broad like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(A1:A80)))>0,"Incomplete","Complete")
```

For dynamic range try:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1))))>0,"Incomplete","Complete")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Excel doesn't seem to like the "#N/A" part of the equation

Comment: try the bottom version... are you after all errors?

Comment: Will do absolutely, just have to wait 5 minutes

Comment: Is this a draining equation if you use it on an entire column?  I'm being told that excel is running out of resources

Comment: I used that range as a simplifying example.  The range is actually much larger

Comment: Try not to use it on an entire column. Any evaluation on an entire column shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Better to use Offset and Count/Counta to get to last row

Comment: Could you possibly include a modified equation with those added.  I'm not familiar with how to do that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169357/discussion-between-qharr-and-oryan5000).

Answer (score 2):

To count **#N/A**'s specifically you can always use something like:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A80,VLOOKUP(,,,))
```

**EDIT#1:**

This formula relies on a tiny trick, you see this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(,,,)
```

returns a **#N/A**.  We deliberately create an error to count a specific type of error.  Another example:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A80,0/0)
```

will count cells with **#DIV/0!** in them.

(It is equally easy to count cells containing **#REF!** or **#VALUE!**)

Comment: @QHarr  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a count, then array enter the formula `=OR(ISNA(SomeRange))`. Array Enter means type the formula in the formula bar, and push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want it to return a message, use something like `=IF(OR(ISNA(SomeRange)),"Complete", "Incomplete")`

If you do need a count, then use `=COUNTIF(SomeRange,NA())`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I want the function to return "Complete" if there is no NAs and "Incomplete" if there is one NA however

Comment: Just amend the formula to `=IF(OR(ISNA(SomeRange)),"Complete", "Incomplete")`